# what is the error in mathematical expressions in the code

Tags: shell, sh

what is the error in the following code. The mathematical expressions seems to be failing
The aim of the code is to read the number from file.txt and calculate mean and variance

Mean

```
 #!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: \"$0\" <filename>"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
        echo "$1 file not found."
        echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
        exit
fi

sum=0
sumSq=0
count=0
arq=$1

while read line
do
        num=`echo ${line//[^0-9]/ }`
        sum=`expr $sum + $num`
        sumSq= `expr $sumSq + $num * $num]`
        count=`expr $count + 1`
done < "$arq"

if [ "$count" != 0 ]
then
        mean=`expr $sum / $count`
        variance=`expr [$sumSq - [$mean * $sum] / $count]`
        printf "Sum= \"$sum\" \n Count= \"$count\"  \n mean= \"$mean\"  \n sumSq= \"$sumSq\" \n variance= \"$variance\""
        exit 0
else
        printf "Sum= \"$sum\" \n Count= \"$count\"  \n Avg= undefined"
        exit 0
fi
```

file.txt

```
Current Offset from Master : 10
Current Offset from Master : 20
```

sh mean file.txt

Comment: Can you show some sample input data and the output being returned by your script?

Answer (score 2):

You have several error/typos here.
For example, in the line:

```
sumSq= `expr $sumSq + $num * $num]`
```

you shouldn't write space between = and `. Also, you have only one `]` here, no `[`.

Also, please note that `/` means integer division; that means that 3/2 is 1 and not 1.